# Python NLTK WUP Similarity Score not unity for exact same word

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, similarity

Simple code like follows gives out similarity score of 0.75 for both cases. As you can see both the words are the exact same. To avoid any confusion I also compared a word with itself. The score refuses to bulge from 0.75. What is going on here?

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
actual=wn.synsets('orange')[0]
predicted=wn.synsets('orange')[0]
similarity=actual.wup_similarity(predicted)
print similarity
similarity=actual.wup_similarity(actual)
print similarity
```

Comment: This is very weird indeed. I would expect a 1.0 but I think I know the reason why. Would reply when i'm free-er tomorrow morning if no one else does so.

Comment: Thank you. Let me also quickly point out that this happens for other words too. Also, it happens even when I explicitly write the strings out. e.g the errors occur even when the variables are defined as 
`actual=wn.synset('apple.n.01')
predicted=wn.synset('apple.n.01')`. Ignore multiple edits, I wanted a newline in comment which apparently is not possible

Comment: I hope the answer helps =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an interesting problem.

**TL;DR**:

Sorry there's no short answer to this problem =(

---

**Too long, want to read**:

Looking at the code for `wup_similarity()`, the problem comes from not the similarity calculations but the way NLTK traverse the WordNet hierarchies to get the `lowest_common_hypernym()` (see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L805).

Normally, the lowest common hypernyms between a synset and itself would have to be itself:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> y = wn.synsets('car')[0]
>>> y.lowest_common_hypernyms(y, use_min_depth=True)
[Synset('car.n.01')]
```

But in the case of `orange` it gives `fruit` too:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> x = wn.synsets('orange')[0]
>>> x.lowest_common_hypernyms(x, use_min_depth=True)
[Synset('fruit.n.01'), Synset('orange.n.01')]
```

We'll have to take a look at the code for the `lowest_common_hypernym()`, from the docstring of https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L805

> Get a list of lowest synset(s) that both synsets have as a hypernym.
>           When `use_min_depth == False` this means that the synset which appears as a
>           hypernym of both `self` and `other` with the lowest maximum depth is returned
>           or if there are multiple such synsets at the same depth they are all returned
>           However, if `use_min_depth == True` then the synset(s) which has/have the lowest
>           minimum depth and appear(s) in both paths is/are returned

So let's try the `lowest_common_hypernym()` with `use_min_depth=False`:

```
>>> x.lowest_common_hypernyms(x, use_min_depth=False)
[Synset('orange.n.01')]
```

Seems like that resolves the ambiguity of the tied path. But the `wup_similarity()` API doesn't have the `use_min_depth` parameter:

```
>>> x.wup_similarity(x, use_min_depth=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: wup_similarity() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_min_depth'
```

Note the difference is that when `use_min_depth==False`, the lowest_common_hypernym checks for maximum depth while traversing synsets. But when `use_min_depth==True`, it checks for minimum depth, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L602

So if we trace the lowest_common_hypernym code:

```
>>> synsets_to_search = x.common_hypernyms(x)
>>> synsets_to_search
[Synset('citrus.n.01'), Synset('natural_object.n.01'), Synset('orange.n.01'), Synset('object.n.01'), Synset('plant_organ.n.01'), Synset('edible_fruit.n.01'), Synset('produce.n.01'), Synset('food.n.02'), Synset('physical_entity.n.01'), Synset('entity.n.01'), Synset('reproductive_structure.n.01'), Synset('solid.n.01'), Synset('matter.n.03'), Synset('plant_part.n.01'), Synset('fruit.n.01'), Synset('whole.n.02')]

# if use_min_depth==True
>>> max_depth = max(x.min_depth() for x in synsets_to_search)
>>> max_depth
8
>>> unsorted_lowest_common_hypernym = [s for s in synsets_to_search if s.min_depth() == max_depth]
>>> unsorted_lowest_common_hypernym
[Synset('orange.n.01'), Synset('fruit.n.01')]
>>> 
# if use_min_depth==False
>>> max_depth = max(x.max_depth() for x in synsets_to_search)
>>> max_depth
11
>>> unsorted_lowest_common_hypernym = [s for s in synsets_to_search if s.max_depth() == max_depth]
>>> unsorted_lowest_common_hypernym
[Synset('orange.n.01')]
```

---

This weird phenomena with `wup_similarity` is actually highlighted in the code comments, https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L843

```
# Note that to preserve behavior from NLTK2 we set use_min_depth=True
# It is possible that more accurate results could be obtained by
# removing this setting and it should be tested later on
subsumers = self.lowest_common_hypernyms(other, simulate_root=simulate_root and need_root, use_min_depth=True)
```

And when the first subsumer in the list is selected at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L843:

```
subsumer = subsumers[0]
```

Naturally, in the case of orange synset, fruit is selected first sense it's first of the list that have tied lowest common hypernyms.

To conclude, the default parameter is sort of a feature not a bug to maintain the reproducibility as with NLTK v2.x.

So the solution might be to either manually change the NLTK source to force `use_min_depth=False`:

https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L845

---

**EDITED**

To resolve the problem, possibly you can do an ad-hoc check for same synset:

```
def wup_similarity_hacked(synset1, synset2):
  if synset1 == synset2:
    return 1.0
  else:
    return synset1.wup_similarity(synset2)
```

Comment: You should raise this issue in NLTK github repo or the google-dev group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nltk-dev

Comment: That was fantastic reply @alvas. Thanks a lot. I will indeed open an issue in the repo and post at google-dev about this. But in the meanwhile, I wish there was a quick(er) fix. I use canopy and I'm not sure how to use changed code to integrate with it. I wish the function took an argument to switch that off. But it was a very informative answer, thanks again.

Comment: You can try an ad-hoc check before running `wup_similarity`.